# Does IUserEmailStore save to the database or the entity?

Tags: asp.net-identity

I am writing a custom implementation of `UserStore(T)` in order to interface with an older database schema. Should my implementation of `IUserEmailStore.SetEmailAsync` save this change to the database or just set the email on the user entity? In other words, does the identity system call `UpdateAsync` after calling this method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `UserManager` does call `UpdateAsync` after setting the email.

```
public virtual async Task<IdentityResult> SetEmailAsync(TKey userId, string email)
{
    ThrowIfDisposed();
    var store = GetEmailStore();
    var user = await FindByIdAsync(userId).WithCurrentCulture();
    if (user == null)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException(String.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, Resources.UserIdNotFound,
                    userId));
    }
    await store.SetEmailAsync(user, email).WithCurrentCulture();
    await store.SetEmailConfirmedAsync(user, false).WithCurrentCulture();
    await UpdateSecurityStampInternal(user).WithCurrentCulture();
    return await UpdateAsync(user).WithCurrentCulture();
}
```

Therefore the only thing required from your store is that the email gets set on the user object (and not saved).